# Angular link inside link

Tags: angularjs

I would like to have a div with class "dialog" so when user click on that div anywhere expert links inside it redirects him to one page. And "links" inside that div should redirect user to another page. And return on previous page browser button should return him on correct page. I saw some examples on javascript but they doesn't work for angular and I always get second page when return back.

I have following snippet of code.

```
   <div ng-repeat="dialog in dialogs">
        <div class="dialog row well well-sm">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                 ...
                <a class="msg-heading" href="#!/item/{{ dialog.adv_id }}">
                    {{ dialog.adv_name }}
                </a>
                ....
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it by passing the event object as argument of `ng-click` function and checking `event.target`

```
<div class="dialog row well well-sm" ng-click="doRedirect($event)">
```

Then in controller or directive:

```
$scope.doRedirect = function(event){
     if(!angular.element(event.target).hasClass('msg-heading') ){
          /* not the <a> tag so put your redirect code here */
     }
}
```